# Problem with Java and JavaScript

Tags: 14.04, java, mysql, javascript

So tomorrow I'll be doing some labs for MySQL certification, and since in my country I can't get class training I had to choose Training On Demand (TOD) which is a good way to learn (You have recorded classes and study material), to practice you get some time in what they call labs, to make this labs you need Java and JavaScript working with FireFox. The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to get the plug-ins to work with FireFox.

I have a installed version of Java in my computer.

This is what I get in terminal when I do the java -version command:

*java version "1.7.0_95"*

*OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.4) (7u95-2.6.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)*

I would really appreciate help here, since I need to start my labs tomorrow morning. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[The official Firefox documentation about Java plugins](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/use-java-plugin-to-view-interactive-content) has a guide that will help you solve your problem. However, it says that Java applets do not work with the 64-bit version of Firefox. So please make sure to check what version of Firefox you have.

The guide outlines the following:

1. [Installing or updating Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/manual-plugin-install-linux-136395.html) from the Oracle website.
2. [Test Java is working](http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp?detect=jre) ([alt](http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp)).
3. Make sure Java is enabled.

   1. Click the menu button [image: New Fx Menu] and choose `Add-ons`. The Add-ons Manager tab will open.
   2. In the Add-ons Manager tab, select the `Plugins` panel.
   3. Click on the **Java** plugin to select it.
   4. If Java is disabled, click on `Never Activate` to open its drop-down menu and select the option to activate Java. The recommended (default) option is `Ask to Activate`, which lets you run Java when prompted.

Comment: The questions you asked would be best as a comment to the original question, since they do not bring value to your answer.

Comment: Are you suggesting to put my answer as a comment rather than an answer, or to delete the question(s)?

Comment: The answer you gave about following the guide is perfect, although it would be better if you outlined the steps here, however all the other questions would be better as a comment to the OP's question. Such as the "What version of Firefox are you using?" and "Are you talking about Java applets?" - that way your answer is an answer and not a mixture of questions and answers.

Comment: I believe the correct answer is that Java doesn't run in 64-bit version of Frefox which I assumed Lazzari is using from the version of OpenJDK in the question. Can I change questions to assumptions?

Comment: I've made an edit to your question to show you what I mean, however it needs to be reviewed by someone else before you will be able to see it. You can see the edit I made by going to [here](http://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/532825).

Comment: Thanks, I could put your edit to the answer, but then you wouldn't get points for the edit :)

Comment: Don't worry, just leave it for now, someone will approve it soon - since you deserve the points for pointing in the right direction. I'll be happy with the review edit points.